# Flask Docker container says it cant locate module "Flask"

Tags: python, docker, flask

This is my DockerFile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y python-pip python-dev build-essential

COPY . /app
ENV HOME=/app
WORKDIR /app


RUN pip install -r requirements.txt


EXPOSE 8000

ENTRYPOINT ["gunicorn", "-b", "0.0.0.0:8000", "-w", "4", "app:app"]
```

Everything builds smoothly I see in the logs that all of the modules get installed via:

`pip install -r requirements.txt`

yet whenever I run:

`docker start -ai backend`

it errors and says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 1, in <module>
    from backend import app
  File "/app/backend/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import render_template, Flask
ImportError: No module named flask
```

Edit: My requirements.txt file has the required modules I can run the gunicorn command from the command line and it fires up the server perfectly.

Requirements.txt file:

```
certifi==2018.4.16
chardet==3.0.4
click==6.7
Flask==0.12.2
Flask-Cors==3.0.7
Flask-MySQL==1.4.0
gunicorn==19.7.1
idna==2.6
itsdangerous==0.24
Jinja2==2.10
MarkupSafe==1.0
PyMySQL==0.9.3
requests==2.18.4
six==1.12.0
urllib3==1.22
Werkzeug==0.14.1
```

Edit #2

I have found out that doing:

`sudo docker run -it backend:latest bash`

makes it work but i cannot access the website.

Comment: Show us the `requirements.txt` file.

Comment: Have you mapped the container port to a host port? e.g. `-p 8000:8000`

Comment: Yes I did and it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `pip freeze` and check if Flask is installed on your environment. Are you using Python 2 or Python 3? I recommend you to run with pip3. So, try with `pip3 install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: I am in a virtualenv and it is installed on the virtualenv, it is not installed on my system

Comment: Ok, you need to activate your venv. Have you done that?